# Telegraf input plugin for SNMP stopped polling

Tags: grafana, influxdb, snmp, telegraf

My Telegraf app stopped polling for SNMP (as seen by the dip in the Sent traffic from the VM) and then started working on its own after a day. Can someone please help me on how to debug this issue? The graph confirms that the VM on which telegraf is running stopped sending any polling data out.
[image]

Comment: You will want to review the telegraf logs around that time frame and see what happened. It could be at timeout, or some sort of delay in obtaining the metrics. Without seeing what actually happened from the logs, you can only guess as to the root cause.